# Android-IndexOutOfBound Exception

Tags: android

I have wrote an adapter for the gridView to display photo which is download from internet and part of the code is listed as follow

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    int mGalleryItemBackground;
    private Context mContext;

    public ArrayList<Drawable> drawablesFromUrl = new ArrayList<Drawable>();

    public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
    }

    public void addItem(Drawable item) {
        drawablesFromUrl.add(item);
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return drawablesFromUrl.size();
    }

    public Drawable getItem(int position) {
        return drawablesFromUrl.get(position);
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {  // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
            imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
            imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(85, 85));
            imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
            imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
        } else {
            imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
        }

        imageView.setImageDrawable(drawablesFromUrl.get(position));
        return imageView;

    }//View getView

}//class ImageAdapter
```

It work properly and the downloaded photo was stored in the ArrayList "drawablesFromUrl.get(position)"

Now I have wrote an intent to open another activity to shown an individual photo in the imagView and part of the code is list as follow:

```
SitePhotoGallery pg = new SitePhotoGallery();
ImageAdapter imageAdapter = pg.new ImageAdapter(this);

Drawable dPhoto=imageAdapter.drawablesFromUrl.get(position); //(ERROR in this line)
BitmapDrawable bPhoto  = (BitmapDrawable) dPhoto;
Bitmap snoop = bPhoto.getBitmap();

//Bitmap snoop = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),imageAdapter.mThumbIds[position]);
img.setImageBitmap(snoop);  
img.setMaxZoom(4f);        
setContentView(img);
```

It prompt an error:

> 07-11 15:22:11.458: E/AndroidRuntime(12856): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.android.mcsis/com.android.mcsis.SitePhotoFullScreen}:  java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0

I guess the arraylist `imageAdapter.drawablesFromUrl.get(position);` is empty. Anything I got wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ImageAdapter imageAdapter = pg.new ImageAdapter(this);

I think you are creating the new instance of ImageAdapter  inner class.
So the previously stored arraylist bitmap data will be lost as it used to belong to different object.

Instead of this try using Application class object if you want to keep some data alive throughout your application . Its pretty simple and nice. And can get its instance 
by context.getApplicationContext().

Comment: can you elaborate more how to use Application class object? I have no idea how to use, thanks!

Comment: Please look into the below link .http://www.devahead.com/blog/2011/06/extending-the-android-application-class-and-dealing-with-singleton/